# replacing characters in a single field of a comma-separated list

Tags: c#, string

I have string in my c# code

```
a,b,c,d,"e,f",g,h
```

I want to replace "e,f" with "e f" i.e. ',' which is inside inverted comma should be replaced by space.

I tried using string.split but it is not working for me.

Comment: Just to be clear... that whole thing is a string correct? as in, it's a string within a string?

Comment: @musefan yes that whole thing is string

Comment: is it possible that there will be more than one comma within a substring? for example, ``"e,f,g"`, and both should be replaced with spaces?

Comment: @musefan yes it is possible & both comma should be replaced by space

Comment: please edit your answer to include the exact requirements discussed in these comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the scenario where you only need to match **one pair of letters**, the following regex will work:

```
string source = "a,b,c,d,\"e,f\",g,h";
string pattern = "\"([\\w]),([\\w])\"";
string replace = "\"$1 $2\"";
string result = Regex.Replace(source, pattern, replace);
Console.WriteLine(result); // a,b,c,d,"e f",g,h
```

Breaking apart the pattern, it is matching any instance where there is a "X,X" sequence where X is any letter, and is replacing it with the very same sequence, with a space in between the letters instead of a comma.

You could easily extend this if you needed to to have it match more than one letter, etc, as needed.

For the case where you can have **multiple letters separated by commas** within quotes that need to be replaced, the following can do it for you. Sample text is `a,b,c,d,"e,f,a",g,h`:

```
string source = "a,b,c,d,\"e,f,a\",g,h";
string pattern = "\"([ ,\\w]+),([ ,\\w]+)\"";
string replace = "\"$1 $2\"";
string result = source;
while (Regex.IsMatch(result, pattern)) {
    result = Regex.Replace(result, pattern, replace);
}
Console.WriteLine(result); // a,b,c,d,"e f a",g,h
```

This does something similar compared to the first one, but just removes any comma that is sandwiched by letters surrounded by quotes, and repeats it until all cases are removed.

Comment: If you read the comments on the question, the OP says it needs to cope with more than two letters in the inner quotes too. For example, `"d,e,f"`

Comment: am I missing something?... the OP clearly stated the need for dealing with more than one comma within inner string, yet has accepted this answer?

Comment: @musefan I updated the answer to address the second case of multiple letters

Answer (score 3):

OK, I can't be bothered to think of a regex approach so I am going to offer an old fashioned loop approach which will work:

```
string DoReplace(string input)
{
    bool isInner = false;//flag to detect if we are in the inner string or not
    string result = "";//result to return

    foreach(char c in input)//loop each character in the input string
    {
        if(isInner && c == ',')//if we are in an inner string and it is a comma, append space
            result += " ";
        else//otherwise append the character
            result += c;

        if(c == '"')//if we have hit an inner quote, toggle the flag
            isInner = !isInner;
    }

    return result;
}
```

NOTE: This solution assumes that there can only be one level of inner quotes, for example you cannot have `"a,b,c,"d,e,"f,g",h",i,j"` - because that's just plain madness!

Comment: There are variants of CSV that allow double-quotes to be escaped inside double-quotes. So it isn't madness, but it's probably OK to ignore it for the sake of simplicity as long as you know your inputs won't ever contain such things.

Comment: @MarceloCantos... well you would need an escape character for that anyway, and it definitely isn't part of the OP requirements. That said, my loop approach would make it fairly easy to add such functionality

Answer (score 2):

Here's a somewhat fragile but simple solution:

```
string.Join("\"", line.Split('"').Select((s, i) => i % 2 == 0 ? s : s.Replace(",", " ")))
```

It's fragile because it doesn't handle flavors of CSV that escape double-quotes inside double-quotes.

Comment: I'll upvote this because it's obviously correct, and a bit clever too. But I am not sure I would ever use it personally... just makes me feel a bit queezy

Comment: @musefan: (This isn't a personal criticism; yours is an exceedingly common reaction; I'm just keen to grok the psychology behind it…) Why does something that is clear, obvious and simple make you so uncomfortable? If it's because of the splitting on quotes, which cuts across the “obvious” splitting on commas, then fair enough. But if it's the high semantic density per character that bothers you, I'll say this: mainstream languages operate at far too low a level of abstraction; C#'s LINQ is a small but very important step in the right direction. We should demand more of this from our languages.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
        string str = "a,b,c,d,\"e,f\",g,h";
        string[] str2 = str.Split('\"');
        var str3 = str2.Select(p => ((p.StartsWith(",") || p.EndsWith(",")) ? p : p.Replace(',', ' '))).ToList();
        str = string.Join("", str3);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `Split()` and `Join()`:

```
string input = "a,b,c,d,\"e,f\",g,h";

string[] pieces = input.Split('"');

for ( int i = 1; i < pieces.Length; i += 2 )
{
    pieces[i] = string.Join(" ", pieces[i].Split(','));
}

string output = string.Join("\"", pieces);

Console.WriteLine(output);
// output: a,b,c,d,"e f",g,h
```

Comment: That replaces all commas. The OP clearly stated that they only want to replace the one inside the quoted string.

Comment: @MarceloCantos I'll adjust my answer.

Comment: @StevenLiekens my string is a,b,c,d,"e,f",g,h & not a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h this.

Comment: @vaibhavshah I've updated my solution, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: You can avoid the test by replacing `i++` with `i += 2`. Also, you forgot to reintroduce the quotes.